# EclipseLink (JPA 2.1) Query not returning results where it clearly should

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to retrieve the next page of results from the database using the code below.

```
   public Collection<Product> getCategoryProducts(Category selectedCategory, String start) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.categoryId = :categoryId")
                .setParameter("categoryId", selectedCategory)
                .setMaxResults(20);
        if (null != start) {
            query.setFirstResult(Integer.parseInt(start));
        }
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

My Product table has about 1000 rows where each product belongs to a category.
If I pick a category like category 1 which has 80 products. I am able to view 4 pages of products each with 20 products. Problem comes in when I try to access products belonging to a higher categoryId. I can only view the first 20 results but the next page returns 0 results.
E.g category 15 has products ranging from `id=459 to id=794 where id is the primary key`.

the query will return the first 20 results when I access the category page from `https://localhost:8181/myapp/category?categoryId=15` but clicking the more link at the bottom `https://localhost:8181/myapp/category?categoryId=15&start=478` returns 0 results. What am I missing?

see also this question [is similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121865/jpa-pagination-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my error. Apparently the position I am setting for first result should be a product of the `page number and the page size`. In my case I was setting first result as the `Id` of the entity I am retrieving. as a result for the first few pages, the result size contained the `ID` but as the page numbers increased the `id` is not contained within the result set. This is the kind of mistakes you don't know that you don't know until you know that you don't know.

```
public Collection<Product> getCategoryProducts(Category selectedCategory, String page) {
    int pageSize = 20;
    EntityManager entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("techbayPU").createEntityManager();
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.categoryId = :categoryId ORDER BY p.id", Product.class);
    query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    if (null != page) {
        query.setFirstResult(Integer.parseInt(page) * pageSize);
    }
    query.setParameter("categoryId", selectedCategory);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```